# Absorption spectrum in the presence of both dopant and exciton energy levels in a semiconductor

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

How will the absorption spectrum of a doped semiconductor look if we consider both the dopant as well as the exciton energy levels? And qualitatively, what is the difference between the formation of an e-h pair corresponding to an exciton energy state, and similarly, another e-h pair corresponding to any of the dopant energy states?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on just what you mean by "e-h pair corresponding to any of the dopant energy states". Do you mean an excitonic complex? The classic Pankove book Optical Processes in Semiconductors is a good reference.

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to the case wherein an electron occupies the donor energy level and the corresponding hole occupies the VB...although is this case similar to an exciton? I'm not pretty clear on this aspect.

Comment: An electron occupying a donor level leaves a neutral dopant, so there is nothing to bind with so perhaps I'm missing something again. But lets start with a donor dopant with the electron still on it. This is a bound state. Are there excited states of that atom, akin to the $n=2,3,...$ states of hydrogen? Well, yes, but they will be above the conduction band edge, and there will be no barrier to the electron just wandering off into the crystal energy states. These are not bound states. Exciton complexes involve a charged dopant atom and multiple free carriers.

Comment: This means that the donor energy level that's drawn for an n-type material represents only the ground state of the electron bound to the donor dopant, please correct me if I'm wrong in this implication...

Comment: First, there are several impurities that have multiple, charge dependent, states in the gap. Phosphorous is the prime example, given that the diffusivity depends on charge state and thus on the Fermi level. Second, dopant (any impurity) levels do not exist for 'real' on an $E$ vs $k$ diagram - the levels are localized, not Bloch states, and have no defined crystal momentum $k$. That doesn't mean it is wrong to sketch an energy 'level' as a reminder. Kind of like how the diagram of energy levels in a diode doesn't show the full 3D band structure. Consider it an analogy, not truth.